# Open dialog in a transparent activity in a "Share via" use case android

Tags: android, android-activity, transparency, android-dialog

How can I open a dialog instead of activity in a "share via" use case.
When user press the "Share via", I would like to show a dialog so the activity of the application that send the share intent will still be visible in the background.
Pinterest does this with their "Create Pin" use case.
(When I pressing the "Create Pin" the only thing that shown to me its a "Browsing for images" dialog)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can open this kind of dialog by calling other app's Intents on the device like this

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = yourActivity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent targetedShareIntent = null;

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            targetedShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");

            switch(packageName){ // works with java 7 
                case "com.twitter.android" :
                    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "shared content on twitter");
                    break ;
                case "com.facebook.katana" :
                    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "shared content on facebook");
                    break ;
                case "com.google.android.gm" :
                    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "shared content on Gmail");
                    break ;
                default :
                    targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "shared content on other app");
            }

            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Share via");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);
    }
```

Comment: In this case I have my activity in the background. What I meant is that when a user call to "Share via" my app, I would like that my app will show a progress dialog until I finished the background job. In that time I would like just a progress dialog, the background should be the activity of the other application (the one that the "share via" is done) Try to do "Create Pin" via dolphin browser or something similar and you'll see what I meant.